# How to trigger a pop-up window on a button click?

Tags: jquery, modalpopups

The button is derived from user control. I want to associate a pop-up window on click of that particular butoon. I can able to achieve this on click of anyother buttons on my base page but as that particular button is coming from a user control I am not able to trigger the pop-up window.

```
$('#btnSendOrder').click(function() {// code here}) // btnSendOrder is from a user control.In this case pop-up is not coming.

$('#btnSendOrder').click(function() { // code here}) // btnSend Order is from the base page itself. In this scenario pop-up comes out.
```

Comment: Maybe I am seriously missing something here - you forgot to tell us what programming language/paradigm this is.Just a lot of talk about buttons and popups...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question.  The two code samples are functionally, identical.  You need to explain the context.  What are 'user control' and 'base page' referring to?

Comment: You should really consider adding the server tag instead of hardcoding the id, asi it won't work if your usercontrol changes containers. Check my answer for a better way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using .NET, reember that your controls will end up looking something like:
ctl1.UserControlName.ButtonName or something like that.

Check your markup code once it is rendered, then use the exact button name so that your jQuery knows which control to fire from.

Comment: Also take a look at what @Juan Manual did below.  Ideally you should grab the ClientID, instead of hard coding it because depending on where that button lives in your app, its clientID might change.  Just a heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Since the button is being rendered on the server, its client ID is not what you are using

You can do this...

```
$('#<%= btnSendOrder.ClientID %>').click(function() {// code here})
```

... from your usercontrol, and the portion between <% and %> will be replaced with the real control id in the client html

Answer (score 0):

Using a bit of jquery, it would be relatively trivial to associate the button with a click event on load of the page:

```
    $(".button").click(function() {
        PopupMyWindow();
    });
```